# How do I border an image by selecting a part of the title?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hope you can help me solving my problem.

These two images are linked somewhere on a site.

```
<a href="?FRUIT=banana><img height="40" src="../../banana.jpg?format=raw" title="Banana - yellow"></a>

<a href="?FRUIT=apple><img height="40" src="../../apple.jpg?format=raw" title="Apple - green"></a>
```

I want to border them to start writing a function.

As you can see the title of each image contains the fruit and a color which should be associated by hearing the fruit.

I started creating an array.

```
var colors = ['yellow','green'];
```

Each element of the array should be bordered by 3px dotted green.

```
for(var i = 0;i < colors.length;i++){
.css('border','3px dotted green');
}
```

But how do I get the title of the image containing the color to border it with 3px dotted green?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0;i < fruits.length;i++){
 $('img[title$='+fruits[i]+']').css('border','3px dotted green');
 var title =  $('#'+fruits[i]).attr('title');
}
```

this is how you can get the title and will border all the images which title end with any of the colors in fruits array.

Comment: I don't get any error message, but the images aren't bordered though. Any idea why? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you so much. Man, I've been looking for hours for the right syntax. Ty again :)

Answer (score 0):

for clarity it would probably be better to use an object to reference your colors by fruit name.

```
var fruit_colors = {Banana: "yellow", Apple: "red", Lime: "green", Grape: "purple"};
for(k in fruit_colors){
  $("img[title^=" + k).css("border","3px dotted " + fruit_color[k])
}
```

Comment: Hm, there was a ) missing, but that is not the problem. Is the syntax of your array correct? never seen it before.

Comment: `this.attr("title")` will first need to be split as it contains both the Fruit and colour.